# If the probability measure $\mu$ is a left-eigenvector to the eigenvalue $1$ of a stochastic matrix $p$, then $\mu p^n=\mu$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let

- $E$ be an at most countable set and $\mathcal E$ be the discrete topology on $E$
- $p=\left(p(x,y)\right)_{x,y\in E}$ be a stochastic matrix
- $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$

> Let's define $$\mu p^n\left(\left\{x\right\}\right):=\sum_{y\in E}\mu\left(\left\{y\right\}\right)p^n(y,x)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N\text{ and }x\in E$$ and assume, that $\mu p=\mu$. How can we show, that we need to have $$\mu p^n=\mu\;,$$ too?

Comment: Yes we can, since $\mu p=\mu$. Is this your question?

Comment: @Did As you may guess, the question had an implicit "If yes, how?", but I've edited the question and made that explicit.

Comment: As I've written under martini's answer: I know that we only need to show $\mu p^2=\mu$ by an inductive argument. Moreover, this equality is trivial, if $E$ is finite. The real question is, why we can use associativity of matrix multiplication if $E$ is countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. As matrix multiplication is associative, we have
$$ \mu p^n = (\mu p^{n-1})p $$
Now start with $\mu p = \mu$ and use induction.

Comment: Is matrix multiplication really associative, when $E$ is countable? I wasn't sure about this.

Comment: As long as all entries of your matrices are non-negative, everything is fine.

Comment: Shouldn't we better state, that $$\mu p^n=(\mu p)p^{n-1}=\mu p^{n-1}$$ and then apply induction?

Comment: This also works. My idea was to go like this: For $n=1$, we have $\mu p = \mu$ by assumption, now suppose $\mu p^{n-1} = \mu$ holds true, we have $$ \mu p^n = (\mu p^{n-1})p = \mu p = \mu $$